# Undefined columns selected when subsetting data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame, `str(data)` to show more about my data frame the result is the following:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   153 obs. of  6 variables:
$ Ozone  : int  41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
$ Solar.R: int  190 118 149 313 NA NA 299 99 19 194 ...
$ Wind   : num  7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
$ Temp   : int  67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
$ Month  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ Day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

However, for example, when I want to subset the amounts of `Ozone` above 14 I use the following code which gives me an error:

```
>  data[data$Ozone > 14 ]
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, data$Ozone > 14) : undefined columns selected

Comment: you're missing a comma.  The error is telling you that you did not indicate which columns to include in your subset.

Comment: In other words, remember data frame references need row and column identifiers.  You can select only one column or all columns, but you need to indicate what you want.

Comment: I'm working on the same assignment, so I know this is homework. Weak sauce.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You want rows where that condition is true so you need a comma:

```
data[data$Ozone > 14, ]
```

Comment: Why... this syntax makes no sense to me

Comment: @Reinderien It's a common way of indexing arrays.  Check out the old school R documentation, which is actually really good at teaching data structures.

Comment: I get everything but the comma.

Comment: `dat[ 1, 2 ]` gives you the entry in the first row, second column.  `dat[ 1, ]` gives you every entry in the first row. `dat[ 1:5, ]` gives you every column of rows 1-5.

Comment: It's 153 x 6, that's two dimensions.