# r ddply error undefined columns selected

Tags: r, plyr

I have a time series data set like below:

```
age time    income
16 to 24    2004 q1 400
16 to 24    2004 q2 500
…   …   
65 and over 2014 q3 800
```

it has different 60 quarters of income data for each age group.as income data is seasonal. i am trying to apply decomposition function to filter out trends.what i have did so far is below. but R consistently throw errors (error message:undefined columns selected) at me. any idea how to go about it?

```
  fun =function(x){
     ts = ts(x,frequency=4,start=c(2004,1))
     ts.d =decompose(ts,type='additive')
     as.vector(ts.d$trend)
}

  trend.dt = ddply(my.dat,.(age),transform,trend=fun(income))
```

expected result is (NA is because, after decomposition, the first and last ob will not have value,but the rest should have)

```
age        time  income  trend     
16 to 24    2004 q1 400  NA 
16 to 24    2004 q2 500  489
…   …
65 and over 2014 q3 800  760
65 and over 2014 q3 810  NA
```

Comment: Please take the time to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include sample data that can easily be imported or copy/pasted into R (yours cannot) and also include the desired results. If you get errors, list the exact errors you receive.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing a comma somewhere, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205806/r-undefined-columns-selected-in-subsetting-my-data-frame