# How to use 'head' in r to show certain variable value?

Tags: r, head

I use `head(df,20)` to see the first twenty rows of my data.
Then I want to see the first twenty rows of my data where VAR1 equal to 1.
I use this `head(df[df$VAR1==1],20)`
But it shows

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, df$VAR1== 1) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

How do I fix it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're subsetting a two-dimensional data.frame, so you need a comma so R knows you're talking about rows instead of columns: `head(df[df$VAR1==1,],20)`

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205806/r-undefined-columns-selected-in-subsetting-my-data-frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alistaire mentioned in the comments***:

`head(df[df$VAR1==1,],20)`

***and if he puts it as an answer I'll delete this so that he can get credit, we just need answers in the answers section and for them to get marked as the solution for the benefit of future readers (most people won't look in comments for a solution)

Comment: FYI: Post is closed off, and there is a very good dupe target.